# INDEX on MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following MYSQL query:

```
SELECT statusdate,consigneenamee,weight,productcode,
  pieces,statustime,statuscode,statusdesc,generatingiata,
  shipmentdate,shipmenttime,consigneeairportcode,signatory 
FROM notes 
where (shipperref='180908184' OR shipperref='180908184' 
       OR shipperref='180908184' OR shipperref='180908184 ' 
       OR shipperref like 'P_L_%180908184')  
order by edicheckpointdate asc, edicheckpointtime asc;
```

I added an index to speed up this query using the MYSQL Workbench but when executing the `EXPLAIN` command, it still does not show the key and shows as NULL:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | dhltracking_2 | ALL  | index2        | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3920874 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

Any reason why this is happening and how I can speed up this query?

My Index:

[image: Index added on table]

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text.

Comment: Please post formatted code text only; not images.

Comment: added text to the post

Comment: How many rows do you get from this query? The execution plan suggests that MySQL assumes that you get a large portion of your table; if you have large amount of rows starting with `P_L_`, this could explain it (as MySQL does not know how many will end with `180908184`). You can try to use `FROM notes force index (index2)`. Another way might be to clean up your data when you insert it (and not everytime you query it) and have a (new, maybe calculated) column that contains exactly the value `180908184` (so removing spaces,prefixes, ...), then you can use a single, indexfriendly `= '180908184'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `LIKE` statement in your query and I think that your index spans on more than 20-30% of table rows (or more..) and that's why MySQL can ignore it for performance reasons.
My proposal:

1. Add `FORCE INDEX` as @Solarflare proposes
2. Use `FULLTEXT` index (works on CHAR and VARCHAR also) and use `MATCH ... AGAINST` search (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)